# how tcan i get block tag with beautifulsoup python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I have to scrap ap page and have this in the HTML code

```
<div id="agentPhone" class="displayNone text large padding bck light_grey"></div>
    </div>
```

in the elenent DOM page I have this

```
<div id="agentPhone" class="displayNone text large padding bck light_grey" style="display: block;"><span>τηλ:</span> <span class="text color bold ">6908511284</span></div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to get 6908... but I can't manage it.
Is there a way to do?

Comment: Please add some more detail, including the code from your own attempt at solving this.

Comment: this is the page https://www.spitogatos.gr/ενοικίαση_Μονοκατοικία_Προφ._Ηλίας__Χανιά_-l5744610   on source code page at 1060 line i have to read a phone number ,this is the line  <div id="agentPhone" class="displayNone text large padding bck light_grey"></div>.Phone is hide.If open field for phone appears number  6908511284 and source code DOM for this is <div id="agentPhone" class="displayNone text large padding bck light_grey" style="display: block;"><span>τηλ:</span> <span class="text color bold ">6908511284</span></div>

Answer (score 1):

It's not because the block style, your problem is because the number show with post request after you click on button, You can not have the number with bs but with selenium.